# EDI Integration

Tags: integrate

Has anyone had any experience integrating Magento with EDI? 
What extensions have worked best for you?

I'm looking at the 'Logicbroker' module. On the other end of the spectrum is there some kind of 'library' that I can import and use within Magento for EDI

**Edit: (EDI Explanation)**

Electronic Data Interchange (EDI) is a 'protocol' that businesses use to send 'documents' (aka business information) to each other electronically.

This is heavily used when one company wants to make a lot of purchases from a supplier, the company that is buying uses a program that sends an EDI document to the supplier.

The supplier does not have to manually process the order since their computers pick it up, parse it and sends it to their ERP (warehouse) which starts the order process.

This allows for much cheaper business since we don't need 'customer representatives' to process the order by phone (or manually typing it in).

Comment: What is EDI? Please explain.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt update with explanation

Comment: Computer talking to computers... nope sorry, no clue :(

Comment: @pzirkind did you manage to integrate this in the end? Our client needs to use this to synchronise stock levels between their stock management system and the new Magento channel.

Comment: @TomBates yes it works pretty well though there is a bit of a learning curve

Comment: @pzirkind if you can provide some insights on your own questoin by answering it, then that would be really great. Thank you.